# Suppress SSIS Warnings for unused output column

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to suppress warning messages of this type in SSIS?

The output column "A" (584) on output "Lookup Match Output" (563) and component "Lookup" (561) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, take a look at [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/678626/disable-ssis-warning-messages)

Comment: That's really too bad. In our case, it takes quite a lot of rework to remove unused columns.

Comment: The MS Connect link is dead now. Redirects to Bing Search.