# How to remove unpivot transformation's unused column warning from dtexec output?

Tags: ssis, warnings

How can you remove the warnings about "unused columns" arising from the `Pivot key value column name` column when using the Unpivot data flow item ...

```
Warning: 2012-05-10 13:30:19.97
   Code: 0x80047076
   Source: Import Client_Categories Table SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: The output column "Client_Categories" (442) on output 
   "Unpivot Output" (224) and component "Unpivot" (222) is not 
   subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output 
   column can increase Data Flow task performance.
End Warning
```

By this I mean actually remove the warning, rather than just not show it in the output ... we want to run `DTEXEC` with the `/WarnAsError` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hack solution I've found to getting rid of the "Unused column" warning that seems to work is to add a `Script Component` to the `Data Flow` and have it use the unused pivot key value

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a global configuration (warnings), not related to a particular component and as far as I'm concern, it cannot be done.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670381/ssis-warning-level)

It mentions "log" but I supposed the principle is the same

Comment: Yeah I'm rapidly coming to that conclusion, the hack with a `Script Component` seems to be the only way ... not sure what the performance hit is

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an `Union All` component after the latest component where a column is used, and delete the column in the `Union All` component.

That way the column is really gone in the rest of the pipeline.